# Delete photo on button click from carousel with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, bootstrap-4

The HTML code below is an empty carousel made with bootstrap 4.

Then the function `previewImages()` uploads a `div.carousel-item` with a photo inside it into the carousel.

When the button `#delete-btn` is clicked, the active carousel button is removed.

```js
function previewImages() {

  var $preview = $('#preview');
  if (this.files) $.each(this.files, readAndPreview);

  function readAndPreview(i, file) {

    if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
      return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
    } // else...

    var reader = new FileReader();

    if ($preview.children().length == 0) {
      if (i === 0) {
        $(reader).on("load", function() {
          $preview.append('<div class="carousel-item active" id="carouselItem"><img class="d-block" src="' + this.result + '"></div>');
        });
      } else {
        $(reader).on("load", function() {
          $preview.append('<div class="carousel-item" id="carouselItem"><img class="d-block" src="' + this.result + '"></div>');
        });
      }
    } else {
      $(reader).on("load", function() {
        $preview.append('<div class="carousel-item" id="carouselItem"><img class="d-block" src="' + this.result + '"></div>');
      });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  }

}

$('#file-input').on("change", previewImages);


function deletePhoto() {

  $("#preview div.active").remove();
  // $(".carousel-item:first-child").addClass("active");

}

$('#delete-btn').on("click", deletePhoto);
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="photo-upload d-flex" id="photo-upload">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" id="preview"></div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-menu text-center">
      <label class="photo-input" class="btn photo-input">
                        Выбрать файл <input id="file-input" type="file" name="photo" multiple hidden>
                    </label><br>
      <button class="btn btn-link delete-btn" id="delete-btn">Удалить фото</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But this function deletes **all** carousel elements!

Please help, I haven't been able to solve this problem for days.

Comment: If `$("#preview div.active").remove();` removes all the images, that suggests that all of them have the active class.

Comment: @Taplar They're calling it using `$('#file-input').on("change", previewImages);`.

Comment: And each input only selects one file at a time?

Comment: @Taplar `this.files` is an object isn't it?

Comment: `this.files` is an array or an array like object.  However if there file selectors are not setup to be multi-select, they will at most only ever be one element in the array. @Zera  Edit: which it does have the `multiple` on it, so it could be multiple

Comment: @Taplar Are you sure `this.files` isn't an object? If I display `this.files` in an alert, it displays `[object FileList]` and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) web docs refers to it as an object.

Comment: `FileList` is an array like object.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Comment: @Taplar So it is an object, which means it wouldn't pass an index and a value as arguments, it would pass the property name and property value (according to [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)).

Comment: Refer to the MDN link I just provided.  It is an array like object that accepts bracket notation with an index.  `FileList` is not a jQuery concept.  It is a javascript native construct

Comment: @Taplar Would it be better to put `$(reader).on("load", function() {})` outside of whole if statement? By the way, I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/gsxnta5h/) that demonstrates the index does increment for each file, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Having the `load()` outside of the if/else block would allow those repeated operations to be reduced, ya.  Would most likely be a good idea.  And yeah, if multiple files are selected, the index would advance.  That's why I deleted the answer I had posted.  The only way multiple entries should get the active class is if the method is being called multiple times with different file lists, and those calls are happening fast enough that no files are loaded and added as children.  Outside of that, it's not clear from the logic provided why multiple elements are getting the active class. @Zera